# gitignore how to ignore wwwroot/lib and wwwroot/dist folders visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, gitignore

I need to exclude wwwroot/lib and wwwroot/dist folders from the git repository.

The folders i want to exclude looks like this:

```
+-Web
+--wwwroot
+---lib
+---dist
```

the gitignore file has below configuration:

```
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
[Ll]og/
```

Any help is much appreciated.. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just add this to your .gitignore file

```
wwwroot/lib 
wwwroot/dist
```

Comment: If you're on Windows, **do not** use the back-slash character.  Use the forward-slash as shown above.